# internet radio proxy

Tags: raspbian, gnuradio

I have several internet radios, (some of which are raspberry Pi), and I have very slow internet.. so I was wondering.

Can I setup my own internet radio proxy? so that I download the live stream only once, but share this to my other internet radio players?

and maybe play local content if stream goes down? (like my own internet radio local y).

anyone have any suggestions where I can start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now here's something I haven't come across in ages, but I do remember a bit of software that would do this. Found it. [Streamripper](http://streamripper.sourceforge.net/) is designed to rip streams to MP3 files, but more importantly also create a relay server (the -r) argument. You can use the relay feature to listen on more than one system. On the downside you'll have to have a system with some free space to hold onto the MP3s it generates until you get around to deleting them.

```
 streamripper http://scastsrv2.shoutcast.com:8038/ -r
```

Comment: Thanks! I will look into the Streamripper, try it. and if it works I will be sure to give you this one.

Comment: this worked just like I wanted.. ok it saves mp3 files, but that is 1) a bit cool and 2) I can cleanup that with a cleanup script.  thanks a lot! very cool little project this